# Upload a file located inside a jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm trying to upload a file located inside a jar. When I upload the file normally it works fine (which is expected because the file is on the file system) but when I package a jar with the file located inside it doesn't work.
I've tried to use:

> this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("big_bird.txt") 
>    //doesn't work
>
> new File("big_bird.txt".toURI()) 
>    //doesn't work
>
> this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("big_bird.txt") //kinda work as in I see the path but I can't get the file

I need to be able to grab the file and upload it all while its inside the jar so can anyone give me some insight into how this can be done?

Comment: Did you need a physical file? If yes, create a temporary file, fill it with the contents of the resource you should be able to read via the classloader and upload the temporary file. Why can't you get the actual file? Because it is packaged inside of a JAR and not present as a physical file the moment you are running the JAR.

Comment: What does "can't get the file" mean? How exactly are you trying to "upload" it?

Comment: Yes I need the physical file. When I said "can't get the file" I mean I can't manipulate the file to upload. How I'm uploading is by using selenium `locator.sendKeys(/pathToFile/"big_bird.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the file as a stream from the jar

`InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("big_bird.txt");`

2. Create a temp file

`File tempFile = File.createTempFile("big_bird", "txt");`

3. Write input stream to temp file

```java
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    int read;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
}
```

4. Now you can use/upload `tempFile`

Comment: I will try this and if it works I will return and accept as the answer. Thanks